# Makefile Hell - A noob with a bugger of an error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Apparently, this error:

```
makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

is the result of not using tabs when invoking compiler commands within makefiles. Here's the problem:

```
main.o : main.cpp mylib.h
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

I already have a tab. Yet, I still get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Hexdump output:

```
0000000 6c23 6261 2e31 616d 656b 2d20 202d 6874
0000010 7369 6920 2073 2061 6f63 6d6d 6e65 2074
0000020 696c 656e 202c 6769 6f6e 6572 2064 7962
0000030 6d20 6b61 2065 7475 6c69 7469 0a79 6d0a
0000040 6961 2e6e 206f 203a 616d 6e69 632e 7070
0000050 6d20 6c79 6269 682e 200a 2020 6720 2b2b
0000060 2d20 2063 616d 6e69 632e 7070 230a 6261
0000070 766f 2c65 7720 2065 7261 2065 6173 6979
0000080 676e 7420 6168 2074 616c 3162 6f2e 7475
0000090 6420 7065 6e65 7364 6f20 206e 616d 6e69
00000a0 2e31 2c6f 6120 646e 6d20 6c79 6269 6f2e
00000b0 202e 230a 6f74 6320 6572 7461 2065 616c
00000c0 3162 6f2e 7475 202c 6874 2065 2b67 202b
00000d0 6f63 6d6d 6e61 2064 6873 776f 206e 6e6f
00000e0 7420 6568 6e20 7865 2074 696c 656e 6920
00000f0 2073 6967 6576 0a0a                    
00000f8
```

Comment: What makes you so sure you have a tab (and nothing else)? Check a hexdump of the makefile.

Comment: What's the hex code for tab? I'm writing this in vim, too, if that means anything. But as to answer your question, I'm positive because I've tried backspacing the entire thing, double tabbing it, etc. and have found nothing to work. Just a single tab is all I have.

Comment: Um, a `hexdump -C` is much easier to interpret. But a tab is `09`, and there are none of those in your dump.

Comment: what's the default tab space amount? 4 spaces? 5 spaces? If so, can I just replicate that without using the tab?

Comment: `make` wants, _specifically_, a **tab character**. It _will not_ work with _any_ amount of spaces. (If you cannot get vim to produce a tab character, ask a question with the vim tag to attract people who might be able to help you with that).

Answer (score 2):

Decoding your hex dump, we find that the start of the compiler line has 4 spaces instead of a tab.

```
0000050 6d20 6c79 6269 682e 200a 2020 6720 2b2b
                            ^^   ^^^^   ^^
```

The four hex 20 in there are indicative.
The complete makefile is:

```
#lab1.make -- this is a comment line, ignored by make utility

main.o : main.cpp mylib.h
    g++ -c main.cpp
#above, we are saying that lab1.out depends on main1.o, and mylib.o. 
#to create lab1.out, the g++ command shown on the next line is give
```

Command lines in a makefile must start with an explicit tab.  (This is one of the primary gotchas with makefiles.  I still have not had a good explanation of why allowing spaces instead would break anything, but history relates that the problem was found very early on in the history of `make`, but it couldn't be fixed because of the existing code base.  And I still don't understand how the change of allowing spaces as well as tabs at the beginning of command lines would have broken anything.)

To fix, turn off 'expand tabs' mode in `vim`:

```
:set noet
```

and ensure that the line does contain an actual tab at the start.
Or ensure that `vim` is syntax-sensitive (so it does not replace tabs with blanks in makefiles).

---

Note that the 'above ...' comment is erroneous.  You are saying nothing about `lab1.out` in this makefile, and nothing about `mylib.o`.  We shall assume that this is because your full makefile does mention these and that you trimmed your makefile to reproduce the problem, but did not trim it to the maximum extent possible.

It is also worth learning to use the macros built into `make`; in fact, you would be best off not specifying the command because `make` knows how to create a `.o` file from a `.cpp` file.  You could simply have written:

```
main.o: mylib.h
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your makefile is probably in a different encoding, maybe UTF8 or something.
I put the text into a hex to ascii converter and this is what comes out!

```
l#ba.1amek-  -htsii  s aocmmne tilen ,gioner dybm ka etuliti
ym
ia.n o :amnic.ppm lybih. 
  g ++-  camnic.pp#
bavo,ew  era easiygnt ah tal1bo.tud penesdo  namni.1,oa dnm lybio. .#
otc erta eal1bo.tu ,ht e+g +ocmmna dhswo nnot ehn xe tileni  sigev
```

Comment: That's just because the hexdump was showing a series of _little-endian_ 16-bit values instead of a series of 8-bit bytes. Swap every second character, and you'll find the plain ASCII content. (Since there are no high-bit bytes, UTF-8 is just the same as ASCII in this case).